# IBM Worklight 5.0.x - How to use console API for automation?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I'm looking for examples to control Worklight appclications via REST API for automation. What I need is a method to disable and enable specific application from command line.

I've found "[HTTP Interface of the production server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_http_interface_of_the_prod_server.html)" on the IBM Worklight Information Center, but it doesn't work.

For exapmle, I sent a GET request to:

```
<WorklightServerURL>/worklight/console/api/getApplications
```

In return I got:

> Error 404: Could not find resource for relative : /getApplications of
>   full path:
>   /worklight/console/api/getApplications".

Looking into the Worklight Console interactions using Chrome developer tool, disabling application request generates:

```
<WorklightServerURL>/worklight/console/api/applications/setAccessRule/17
```

Which is not consistent with the IBM Worklight Information Center...

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a documentation defect, where (in this specific case):

```
http://myhost:port/console/api/{Action}
```

Should be

```
http://myhost:port/console/api/applications/{Action}
```

For example:

```
http://myworklightserver:8080/console/api/applications/all
http://myworklightserver:8080/console/api/applications/get/testapp
```

I have opened a documentation defect to update the Console API Requests section. Thanks.

---

As for `setAccessRule`,

- The API request structure is: `http://myworklightserver:8080/console/api/applications/setAccessRule`
- The parameters are:

  - `gadgetAppId` (Required. You can find this in the database)
  - `action` (Required. delete | notify | block)
  - `message` (Required)
  - `downloadLink` (Optional)

Note that you are linking to the Worklight 5.0.5 Information Center; the fixes will appear in the Worklight 5.0.6 and 6.0 Information Center pages.

In Worklight 6.0 the port has changed to "10080", and a context root section exists before "/console".

```
http://myworklightserver:10080/mycontext/console/api/applications/all
```

Comment: Idan, thank you. I can get JSON response using "/console/api/applications/all". I need to enable/disable an application, so what URI should I specify? Or can I get correct API reference somewhere?

Comment: @NobuhiroSue, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Comment: hi Idan, Can you please share a sample url for setAuthenticityRule to access disable with a sample messages. if you can share the url that would really help me.

Comment: IBM Knowledge Center.